# Blue Color On Everything After Render

Tags: rendering, light

Please forgive me for asking, I am new to Blender.

While I am rendering I really love my work, then right at the very last second for some reason everything is tinted blue.  I have tried changing the Preferences > Solid OpenGL Lights, amongst a number of other things.

I get all pumped up everytime, then WHAM! blueness smothers everything everywhere on the last 1/10 of a second of rendering.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: Color Change at the last 1/10 of a second of render]

I added more screen shots in the link because I don't have enough street cred to post more than 2 links :)

[Screenshots of Materials & Settings](https://goo.gl/photos/jRZWybdm84V1SZ1D7)

Comment: Probably you have some composite nodes. These are "triggered" right after rendering. Probably color correction or something like that. It's hard to tell without viewing exact setup :)

Comment: Yep, was about to type exactly that. Please edit your question and provide some details we can look at, like render settings, materials, lighting, and compositor setup.

Comment: I put a link to more screen shots... I am a total noob still... sorry.

Comment: To me it looks like it may be the compositing shadows setting?